# Same SQL query taking much more time in a different server

Tags: mysql

I've recently moved a site to a different server, and while the overall performance is better, there's one specific SQL query that's taking about 5 seconds to execute now, while it only takes 0.1 seconds on the old server.

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM wp_ap_activity t1 NATURAL JOIN (SELECT max(activity_date) AS activity_date
FROM wp_ap_activity
WHERE activity_q_id IN(126187,125933,126043,126083,100007,125781,125628,125615,125716,125728,126115,126061,126028,125429,124783,125651,126092,125510,126062,126058,125923,125727,125948,125085,126033,125975,125537,124664,126031,125947,125938,123327,125908,125467,125471,125852,125558,125980,125226,125904,124454,103489,125935,125925,124472,122940,125949,125950,125139,112744,124718,124626,125859,125903,125406,66537,125722,125887,125810,124810,125782,125823,125799,108626,99836,85975,74147,69962,69510,68598,68593,125875,125620,92246,112851,108528,108629,112864,106120,119571,125798,118205,125831,108547,125550,125813,124297,125223,125792,125536,125730,123848,125411,125598,125638,125698,125519,125700,125697,125151,125688,125445,125715,125083,125669,125665,125673,124777,123975,125528,125724,125146,125610,124784,125617,125631,125637,124765,125496,125647,125571,125245,125264,125513,125534,124854,125527,125543,125535,125515,125337,125221,125202,125549,125530,125531,125541,124952,125358,125502,125427,125525,125123,125361,125252,125421,125491,125263,125260,124743)
GROUP BY activity_q_id) t2
ORDER BY t2.activity_date
```

**New Server**

- MySQL Version: 10.3.16-MariaDB-1:10.3.16+maria~jessie
- Execution Time: 5.2812 seconds
- Table Name: wp_ap_activity
- Table Rows: 109,947
- Space Usage:

  - Data: 9.5 MiB
  - Index: 10.5 MiB
  - Effective: 20.1 MiB
  - Total: 20.1 MiB

`SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_ap_activity` results:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_ap_activity` (
 `activity_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `activity_action` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `activity_q_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `activity_a_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `activity_c_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `activity_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `activity_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`activity_id`),
 KEY `activity_q_id` (`activity_q_id`),
 KEY `activity_a_id` (`activity_a_id`),
 KEY `activity_user_id` (`activity_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=113859 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

**Old Server**

- MySQL Version: 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
- Execution Time: 0.1842 seconds
- Table Name: wp_ap_activity
- Table Rows: 109,759
- Space Usage:

  - Data: 1.5 MiB
  - Index: 4.5 MiB
  - Total: 6 MiB

`SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_ap_activity` results:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_ap_activity` (
 `activity_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `activity_action` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `activity_q_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `activity_a_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `activity_c_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `activity_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `activity_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`activity_id`),
 KEY `activity_q_id` (`activity_q_id`),
 KEY `activity_a_id` (`activity_a_id`),
 KEY `activity_user_id` (`activity_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=113657 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

The table structure, primary keys, indexes are identical.
The new table reports it's total size as 20.1 MiB while the old one is much smaller at 6 MiB - I'm not sure why this is happening and if it has to do with the slow performance.

Both tables are `InnoDB` and have collation set to `utf8mb4_general_ci`

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

---

Explain query:
**New Server (performs slow)**

```
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+--+
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                           |  |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+--+
| 1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2>     | ALL   | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL | 970    | Using temporary; Using filesort                 |  |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+--+
| 1  | PRIMARY     | t1             | ALL   | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL | 109514 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |  |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+--+
| 2  | DERIVED     | wp_ap_activity | range | activity_q_id | activity_q_id | 8       | NULL | 970    | Using index condition                           |  |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+--+
```

**Old Server (performs fast)**

```
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref                       | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |  |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--+
| 1  | PRIMARY     | t1             | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                      | 20270 | 100.00   | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |  |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--+
| 1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2>     | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0>   | 5       | helpdesk.t1.activity_date | 10    | 100.00   | Using index                                  |  |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--+
| 2  | DERIVED     | wp_ap_activity | NULL       | range | activity_q_id | activity_q_id | 8       | NULL                      | 970   | 100.00   | Using index condition                        |  |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+--+
```

---

**Updated EXPLAIN after applying the fix provided by Wilson Hauck. Query speed down to ~0.005 seconds!**

```
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra                       |
|----|-------------|----------------|-------|---------------|---------------|---------|------------------|------|-----------------------------|
| 1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2>     | ALL   | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL             | 966  | Using where; Using filesort |
| 1  | PRIMARY     | t1             | ref   | activity_date | activity_date | 5       | t2.activity_date | 1    |                             |
| 2  | DERIVED     | wp_ap_activity | range | activity_q_id | activity_q_id | 8       | NULL             | 966  | Using index condition       |
```

Comment: Did you do an `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: @user3783243 No - it is a WordPress app but the issue is not related to WP or PHP, I've updated the tags.

Comment: Please post CREATE statements for the table from both servers. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_ap_activity`.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I've added EXPLAIN results above. They're identical for both tables.

Comment: @Pail Spiegel added `SHOW CREATE TABLE` results above.

Comment: As I see, the query should be slow on both servers, because there is no index to support the JOIN. You should though post the results of `EXPLAIN <your query>` - Not the EXPLAIN of the table.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` on the query, to see the execution plan. `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: I've updated the post with the explain queries. There are differences, not sure what to make of that though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EXPLAIN`'s are nowhere close to being identical, look at end of lines.  Second query has BNL in remarks, meaning Block Nested Loop processing (that is always SLOW).  To be avoided.

You NEED an index on `activity_date` on EACH table.

Run from MySQL command prompt, `SHOW INDEX FROM wp_ap_activity;` on EACH server will rebuild the indexes so they are current.

Change queries to `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE .........` for testing to avoid using Query Cache results and get your timings again from the SECOND and THIRD execution of each query to compare.

Let us know your results, please.

Comment: Adding an index on activity_date brought the query speed from ~6 seconds to ~0.005 seconds, incredible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Albion Indexes are your ticket to high speed access.  Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile where we have free Utility Script downloads to assist with performance tuning. Visit us, please.